# Swift 3 - Using different orientations programmatically

Tags: swift, orientation

I have an app with video streaming pages. And I need to use that pages as landscape. I am using this code for this

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}
```

And I use UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait for the other pages.

This generally works fine. But sometimes when go to a video page that forgets to force it to landscape and videos cannot display as its supposed to be, because of the orientation problem.

What is the best way to force some pages to landscape?

Comment: The tile is misleading, but that question will tell you how to adjust view orientations on the view controller level

Comment: That worked. And I marked this question as duplicate.